# sqlalchemy query(join) to retrieve sum of votes for a post

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have 3 models

```
class Post(Base):
__tablename__ = "posts"

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
title = Column(String, index=True, nullable=False)
content = Column(String, nullable=False)
published = Column(Boolean)
owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"))

owner = relationship("User")



class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    email = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)


class Vote(Base):
    __tablename__ = "votes"
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"), primary_key=True)
    post_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("posts.id"), primary_key=True)
```

I would like to generate a query that retrieves one or all posts and automatically sum up all of the votes for said post. I know how to do this in sql but not sure how to accomplish this using SQLAlchemy.

The sql query would look like this:

```
SELECT posts.*, count(votes.post_id) as votes from posts left join votes on (posts.id = votes.post_id) where posts.id = 1 group by posts.id;
```

Also is there a way to make it so i don't have to create a custom query and instead have the post model automatically populate the sum of all votes with a reference or something like that?

Comment: You probably want to create a [hybrid attribute](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/hybrid.html).